# Macarons Problems because of convection gas

Tags: meringue, convection, macarons

I tried the pierre herme macaron ispahan recipe:

```
250 g de poudre d’amande

250 g de sucre glace

6 blancs d’œufs (180 g)

3 g de colorant rouge carmin

250 g de sucre semoule

65 g d’eau minérale
```

The problem is not with the recipe. The problem is my oven.

I have a convection oven, where the gaz marker of the bottom area contain degrees (100, 120, ..., 220C). And the bottom mark just contain low and high heat.

The first batch I used the bottom area where I put the temperature on 160 degree C for 20 minutes. The rack was at the middle of the oven. The end result was macarons with no feet. The taste was burnt almond.

The second batch I just used the upper area of the gas and the marker was on high heat (unknown temperature). The rack was in the middle and after 20 minutes I have a good looking macarons. I waited for few minutes and taste one it was hard a little bit with a weird taste (not burnt almond taste, just unknown weird taste).

How can I master the macarons with this type of gas ?

Comment: Do you actually have a thermometer and measure the temperature? Often the onboard thermometers in ovens are poorly calibrated.

Comment: I actually don't have one

Comment: Second @Catija - doing a heat reading of all parts of your oven is essential in this case. Also, have you performed the recipe successfully in another oven? Difficult to determine what the actual issue is without proper control tests.

Comment: What coloring are you using? Sometimes it has a taste of its own. You say that the problems has to be with your oven, but I wonder if the "unknown weird taste" can come from the ingredients after all.

Comment: Powdered coloring I think. Thank you all i will get a thermometer