# Macarons with no feet in convection oven

Tags: eggs, almonds, convection, macarons

I made a french macaron (french meringue) and the result was aweful.

The recipe is:

275 g almond with 250 g powder sugar

6 egg whites with 210g sugar

10 minutes on 160 Celsius.

What was wrong

[image]

Comment: Will try to help on your other question.. you can edit that original (https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/81929/macarons-problems-because-of-convection-gas) with more information, no need to open 2 separate questions for the same issue :)

Comment: if you want us to try and figure out what you did "wrong" you have to tell what you did.

Comment: The macaron feet have been discussed a lot, please refer to the sidebar linked questions. The duplicate target is our main question on them, the specifics of a convection oven can be discussed in your other question. Also, macarons have little tolerance in the creation process, so it is usually not really helpful to guess "what went wrong", it is rarely possible to match symptoms to cause precisely. What is typically needed is practice, trying to stick 100% to the process as described.